# Write SQL script to insert data

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, sql-scripts

In a database that contains many tables, I need to write a SQL script to insert data if it is not exist.

Table **currency**

```
| id     | Code    | lastupdate | rate      |
+--------+---------+------------+-----------+
| 1      | USD     | 05-11-2012 | 2         |
| 2      | EUR     | 05-11-2012 | 3         |
```

Table **client**

```
| id     | name    | createdate | currencyId|
+--------+---------+------------+-----------+
| 4      | tony    | 11-24-2010 | 1         |
| 5      | john    | 09-14-2010 | 2         |
```

Table: **account**

```
| id     | number  | createdate | clientId  |
+--------+---------+------------+-----------+
| 7      | 1234    | 12-24-2010 | 4         |
| 8      | 5648    | 12-14-2010 | 5         |
```

I need to insert to:

1. `currency` (`id=3, Code=JPY, lastupdate=today, rate=4`)
2. `client` (`id=6, name=Joe, createdate=today, currencyId=Currency with Code 'USD'`)
3. `account` (`id=9, number=0910, createdate=today, clientId=Client with name 'Joe'`)

**Problem:**

1. script must check if row exists or not before inserting new data
2. script must allow us to add a foreign key to the new row where this foreign related to a row already found in database (as currencyId in client table)
3. script must allow us to add the current datetime to the column in the insert statement (such as `createdate` in `client` table)
4. script must allow us to add a foreign key to the new row where this foreign related to a row inserted in the same script (such as `clientId` in `account` table)

**Note:** I tried the following SQL statement but it solved only the first problem

```
INSERT INTO Client (id, name, createdate, currencyId)
SELECT 6, 'Joe', '05-11-2012', 1
WHERE not exists (SELECT * FROM Client where id=6);
```

this query runs without any error but as you can see I wrote `createdate` and `currencyid` manually, I need to take currency id from a select statement with where clause (I tried to substitute 1 by select statement but query failed).

This is an example about what I need, in my database, I need this script to insert more than 30 rows in more than 10 tables.

any help

Comment: what are you using? mysql, mssql, oracel?

Comment: and do you want a trigger, stored procedure to do this or maybe a php script?

Comment: i use postgresql, i need a script that can i run it to insert data, whoever what is its type, but i think trigger not suitable here, and stored procedure will be the best way to do this

Comment: You need to select the currency_id from the currency table. You search criterium will be currencycode = 'USD'. Similar for the insert into the account table, which will have to obtain the client_id from the client table. BTW: don't use "name" as a column name in pg. It is a reserved word. (I am not sure about "code", but I would never use that either) BTW: the "not exists" looks good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote

> I tried to substitute 1 by select statement but query failed

But I wonder why did it fail? What did you try? This should work:

```
INSERT INTO Client (id, name, createdate, currencyId)
SELECT 
    6, 
    'Joe', 
    current_date, 
    (select c.id from currency as c where c.code = 'USD') as currencyId
WHERE not exists (SELECT * FROM Client where id=6);
```

Comment: You don't need the subquery. It can be a plain "select ... FROM ...".

Comment: Yes, it could be a plain select. But a subquery also works, and might be clearer. Also, the insert would still work even if the row was not found, just with null.

Comment: It is the kind of place where I would *not* appreciate a nullable foreign key ;-)

Comment: i try your subquery its work, but i still have a problem (number 3). how can i get the current datetime to select it in the daabase?

Comment: @danny-london: The current datetime can be selected using `current_date` as I have used in my example insert statement. PostgreSQL also supports converting the value to a varchar if this is what you require (see the documentation for `cast`).

Comment: i know, but i mean that i need current dateTime, not only current date

Comment: @wildplasser: In the Client table has a constraint (foreign key, or even `not null`), then the insert would fail. Which might be better (clearer) than if no row was inserted at all.

Comment: @danny-london: Well, what about if you use Google or check the PostgreSQL documentation for that?

Comment: thanks Thomas Mueller i found (Now()) function that works fine. thanks all

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can work out if the data exists.
Here is a quick bit of code written in SQL Server / Sybase that I think answers you basic questions:

```
create table currency(
    id numeric(16,0) identity primary key,
    code varchar(3) not null,
    lastupdated datetime not null,
    rate smallint
);

create table client(
    id numeric(16,0) identity primary key,
    createddate datetime not null,
    currencyid numeric(16,0) foreign key references currency(id)
);

insert into currency (code, lastupdated, rate)
values('EUR',GETDATE(),3)

--inserts the date and last allocated identity into client
insert into client(createddate, currencyid)
values(GETDATE(), @@IDENTITY)

go
```

Comment: IMHO there is no "IDENTITY" in sql. You might be confused by Microsoft?

Comment: GETDATE() didn't work, it gives an error (No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.)